# First click not working after short period of inactivity

Tags: macos, mouse, click

OS: OS X 10.7.5
Hardware: Logitech G400s

I'm having a problem with my mouse clicking. I am pretty sure this is not a hardware issue but a software one. The mouse is not registering the first click after just a few (about 5) seconds of inactivity (not clicking). If I click continuously or  every 4 seconds every single click will register.

I previously had this problem before and disabling "enable access for assistive devices" from the Universal Access settings seemed to fix the problem. This seems to have no effect now. I have restarted multiple times and the problem persists.

Any help is very much appreciated as this problem is infuriating to say the least.

EDIT: So I narrowed the problem down a little. If steam + chrome are open at the same time the problem persists. BUT if either/both of them are closed then clicking works as normal. It's very strange behaviour..